# Preparing a dates array with corresponding values

Tags: javascript, jquery, date, momentjs

0:{entry_counts: 2000, week_end_date: "2016-09-01"} 1:{entry_counts: 10000, week_end_date: "2016-09-08"} 2:{entry_counts: 20000, week_end_date: "2016-09-22"} 3:{entry_counts: 40000, week_end_date: "2016-09-29"} 4:{entry_counts: 150000, week_end_date: "2016-10-13"}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since your dates don't contain any sort of timezone or even time data it will be treated as UTC timezone. We don't really need moment to help us out on this one.

You are also using very long references in your code which make it harder to read and more prone to errors. (for example: `data.entryDetails[0].entry_counts[count].entry_counts;`) 
I would suggest cutting this down using some variables. This also make it easier to check if the value is valid or even defined.

When working with time and incrementing time, valueOf is very useful. I wrote a quick script for you. I'm sure it can be improved with some error checking and making sure the data is defined. Other than this it should be useful for you!

Happy holidays!

```js
var countData    = [ {entry_counts: 2000, week_end_date: "2016-09-01"},{entry_counts: 10000, week_end_date: "2016-09-08"},{entry_counts: 20000, week_end_date: "2016-09-22"},{entry_counts: 40000, week_end_date: "2016-09-29"},{entry_counts: 150000, week_end_date: "2016-10-13"} ]
var today        = ( new Date() ).valueOf()

var currentEntry = parseEntry( countData.shift() )
var nextEntry    = parseEntry( countData.length ? countData.shift() : null )


var viewsArray   = []
var datesArray   = []

var time         = currentEntry.dateValue

while( time <= today ){
  
    // update currentEntry data used to the most up-to-date data we have
    if( nextEntry && time > nextEntry.dateValue ) {
      
      while( nextEntry && time > nextEntry.dateValue ){
        
        currentEntry = nextEntry
        nextEntry    = parseEntry( countData.length ? countData.shift() : null )
        
      }
      
    }
      
    viewsArray.push( currentEntry.views )
    datesArray.push( new Date( time ) )
  
    time += daysInMilliseconds(7)

}


console.log( viewsArray )


function parseEntry( entry ) {
  
  if( !entry ) return null
  
  entry.date      = new Date( entry.week_end_date )
  entry.dateValue = entry.date.valueOf()
  entry.views     = entry.entry_counts
  
  return entry
  
}


function daysInMilliseconds( days ) {
  
  return days * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000
  
}
```

Comment: This works like charm! Much cleaner and shorter. Thanks a lot!

Could you please give me a walk through of the code? And what I was doing wrong? :)

Comment: "*I guess we can assume it will be in the local time zone*" but you aren't. Using the Date constructor to parse ISO 8601 format date strings means they will be treated as UTC, so they'll be shifted by the host timezone when compared to dates created by `new Date()`. You'll get incorrect results for certain times of the day and not others.